# Xamarin Android API 25

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I installed the Nuget packages for The Xamarin.Android Support version 25.0.1-rc1.
However, when I build- I get this error:

```
no resource found that matches the given name 'theme.appcompat.light.darkactionbar'
```

And a few more errors like that.
How do I resolve this?

Comment: Are you add `AppCompat`  library to your project?

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki Yes, I did

Comment: Which version android you use to compile this app?

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki I did Compile using Android 7.1

Comment: Could you please check if the libraries are correctly added to your project reference? And please post some detailed error log.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Thanks. I reinstalled everything and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and reinstalled the Support packages, and it works now.